# Multiple laravel horizon workers listen on same queue

Tags: php, laravel, google-kubernetes-engine, horizon

On GKE, I have two replicas of laravel horizon server for consuming queues faster. They are listening to the same queues.

I found out sometimes a job being executed multiple times at the same time.

Is this expected to happen, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: PS: The queue driver is redis.

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/315 for possibilities.